# Log4j cannot find appenders, but they are present

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

I have a problem with logging using log4j. I created my properties file, and opened it in the Java code, and it's all fine, except that the properties file is malfunctioning. I looked through several tutorials and questions around here, but I can't seem to be able to fix it. Here's my properties file (called WSConnectorLog.properties):

```
##########################
# Loggers
log4J.rootLogger = FATAL, console
log4j.WSDetailedLogger = TRACE, WSDetailLog, console
log4j.WSAppLogger = INFO, WSAppLog, console

# Appenders
log4j.appender.console = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] (%F:%L) %p %m%n

log4j.appender.WSDetailLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.WSDetailLog.File=logs/WSDetailed.log
log4j.appender.WSDetailLog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.WSDetailLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.WSDetailLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] (%F:%L) %-5p %m%n

log4j.appender.WSAppLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.WSAppLog.File=logs/ws.log
log4j.appender.WSAppLog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.WSAppLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.WSAppLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

# Set root category priority to INFO and its only appender to console.
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
```

I use it in Java like this:

Preparing:

```
public class WSConnector {

    private static Logger WSDetailedlog = Logger.getLogger("WSDetailedLogger");
    private static Logger WSAppLog = Logger.getLogger("WSAppLogger");
    private ConnectionManager cm = ConnectionManager.getInstance();
    private ConfigHandler config = ConfigHandler.getInstance();
    private SimpleDateFormat format = null;

    /**
     * Protected constructor for the Singleton pattern.
     */
    protected WSConnector() {
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        try {
            props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/WSConnectorLog.properties"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
    }
```

And then writing to:

```
...
WSDetailedlog.info(log);
...
WSAppLog.info("random string";
...
```

I get the following error:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CONSOLE
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CONSOLE".
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (WSDetailedLogger).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CONSOLE
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CONSOLE".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CONSOLE
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CONSOLE".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CONSOLE
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CONSOLE".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CONSOLE
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CONSOLE".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CONSOLE
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CONSOLE".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CONSOLE
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CONSOLE".
```

The environment I'm running this from is a Tomcat 7.0. I exported the jar there, and put the properties file next to it. I'm invoking the jar from an Eclipse Dynamic WebApp project, so that it can see the Tomcat's lib directory. The problem is not that it doesn't find the properties file, but rather that it's malformed somehow.

Could you look at it, and help me understand the problem?

Comment: `-Dlog4j.debug=true`? Obviously your posted configuration and what's available at runtime do not match-up, since you have `console` in config and `CONSOLE` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify a console appender, you have to configure it to a level of logs for example:

```
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
    # Console appender configuration
    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] (%F:%L) %p %m%n
    log4j.appender.stdout.filter.b=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter
    log4j.appender.stdout.filter.b.LevelToMatch=FATAL    
    log4j.appender.stdout.filter.b.AcceptOnMatch=false
```

This is the configuration that I use to print only the FATAL logs.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, well, this resolved the problem with the console appender, but now there is something else. For some reason, it now can't find the other appenders, only the stdout. So, it only logs for the console. Everything. Even the ones that should be written to file. If I comment the stdout appender, I get an error message:

`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (WSDetailedLogger). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.`